# Australian Bridging visa B - BVB - (subclass 020) duration?

Tags: visas, australia, german-citizens, australian-residents

I'm on a Bridging visa and planning to go travel for 2-3 weeks to my home in Georgia. I've been informed I need the **Bridging visa B - BVB - (subclass 020)** to travel outside Australia .

I'm not a Australian citizen. I hold a German passport.

Does anyone know how long it takes to get the visa approved ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you would need a visa if you're an Australian citizen, do you have an Australian passport ?

Comment: I'm not an Australian citizen :D that's why I need the visa to travel

Comment: Ok so why did you add the citizens tag then ? :)

Comment: Soz @blackbird57 , I thought it was related since I'm getting a residence permit and become a citizen soon. I moved to australia because my Aussie wife fell pregnant with twins and since I'm here. In on the bridging visa for 15 months and hopefully I'll receive a confirmation in April, otherwise i need to get that BVB to travel

Comment: Can someone explain the close vote ? This isn't about moving to Australia, the OP already lives there, it's about securing a travel visa to be able to return

Comment: @blackbird57 (I did not VtC) - a guess would be that since he is in the process of getting a residence permit (to Australia) which is a long term status, and since the Bridging visa is a requirement _because he is in that process_, this question might be better served by those more knowledgeable about the residency requirements of Australia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Australian [authority on the matter](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/020-#):

> You should apply for your BVB no more than three months, and not less than two weeks, before the date on which you want to travel.

So the answer seems to be, **two weeks to three months**, which is rather vague so give yourself at least a month to be safe. Also note that generally these guidelines assume you've got all the required paperwork and nothing is missing, so double check !

Answer (score 1):

BVB does not take more than 3 days if u hold a German pass.

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE! Do you have any sources (links, personal experience) to back your answer? As it stands now it can not be verified.